# Shell script to retrieve node NAME from XML file

Tags: xml, shell, nodename

I have a XML file like below, I am trying to retrieve the first child node name and store it in an array and use it for reading the attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="config.xsl"?>
<cell name="servicesPrd">
    <env>Prod </env>
    <console>
        ...
    </console>
    <vhosts>
        ....
    </vhosts>
    <clusters>
        ....
    </clusters> 
    <nodes>
        ....
    </nodes>
</cell>
```

I am looking to retrieve env, console, vhosts, cluster, nodes through shell script

BTW I am able to read the node attributes using xmllint which is working fine, currently hardcoded the nodenames to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlstarlet` is generally useful for querying XML files:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/cell/*' -v 'name()' -n your.xml
env
console
vhosts
clusters
nodes

$ xmlstarlet el your.xml
cell
cell/env
cell/console
cell/vhosts
cell/clusters
cell/nodes
```